# When I try to do a WMS request to geoserver using the leaflet API I am getting a format related error

Tags: geoserver, wms, java, leaflet, http-headers

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The  
document tree is shown below.

<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String d != java.lang.String
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

In the console I am not getting any errors only mimetype warnings and my wms layer isn't showing up on my base map, but it is being read in. So either I need to add something into Geoserver or I need to manually alter the styles which I will need to do in my leaflet code.

Comment: you need to post more of the error message before we can even try to help

Comment: I once saw something similar with a WFS GET request to GeoServer - the client passed in an XML fragment for the `<filter>` parameter and GeoServer got upset because filter was namespaced (`<ogc:filter>`) but because the fragment didn't include namespace declarations GeoServer couldn't figure out what `ogc:` meant. It would be helpful if you could use Fiddler or similar and update your question with the full set of request parameters.